# How to adapt db structure to the expected API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

Let's say I have client side app which expects the following JSON structure as show.

```
{'foo': {'bar': '1'}}
```

I'd like to keep related db structure as:

```
 create_table :foos do |t|
   t.string :baar
 end
```

so I'd like to use `baar` instead of `bar` as name of db column. What do you think about just aliasing this stuff to something like:

```
alias_attribute :bar, :baar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendered json structure is not tied to the database structure you use. The attribute_names can be set in the json render function (and can be same or different from the underlying database field name)

Continuing from the table structure you have:

```
create_table :foos do |t|
  t.string :baar
end
```

This would correspond to the `foo` model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
end
```

The json render function within `foos_controller.rb` - for the show action (for example)- would be as follows:

```
class FoosController < < ApplicationController

  def show
    @foo = Foo.find(1)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { foo: { baar: @foo.bar } } }
    end
  end
end
```

Here, the json attribute - `baar` could be anything, and that is being linked to the `bar` field in the `foos` table.